# Apt-get dist-upgrade -y vs apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, command-line

I have been wondering this off and on and have yet to find my answer anywhere. Can anyone explain why a few sources throw in the -y after the upgrade command? What is it's function.

Answer (score 3):

- `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories
  and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of
  packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories
  and PPAs.

  From https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

  ```
            Used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. 
            The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) 
            specified in /etc/apt/sources.list(5). An update should always be 
            performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade.
  ```
- `apt-get upgrade` will fetch new versions of packages existing on the machine if APT knows about these new versions by way of apt-get update.

  From https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

  ```
            Used to install the newest versions of all packages currently
            installed on the system from the sources enumerated in 
            /etc/apt/sources.list(5). Packages currently installed with new 
            versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no 
            circumstances are currently installed packages removed, nor
            are packages that are not already installed retrieved and 
            installed. New versions of currently installed packages that 
            cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another 
            package will be left at their current version. An update must be 
            performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of 
            packages are available.
  ```
- `-y, --yes, --assume-yes`

  ```
            Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
            run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
            changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
            package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
            abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
  ```

  If you chose not to use `apt-get` with `-y` option, you will need to
  answer to all prompts that you get from that command interactively in
  order for the execution of the command to continue.

Comment: The explanation for the difference between upgrade and dist-upgrade is missing. It's also in the man page, mostly it handles changes (usually caused by a major version switch) from what I understand. Prefixing the "quote" with a > would help the readability I think.